# How to find the first date of the month for a set of data in vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a set of data as such:

```
05/06/2015
04/06/2015
03/06/2015
02/06/2015
29/05/2015
28/05/2015
27/05/2015
26/05/2015
25/05/2015
22/05/2015
21/05/2015
20/05/2015
19/05/2015
18/05/2015
15/05/2015
14/05/2015
13/05/2015
12/05/2015
11/05/2015
08/05/2015
07/05/2015
06/05/2015
05/05/2015
04/05/2015
30/04/2015
29/04/2015
28/04/2015
27/04/2015
24/04/2015
23/04/2015
22/04/2015
21/04/2015
20/04/2015
17/04/2015
16/04/2015
15/04/2015
14/04/2015
13/04/2015
10/04/2015
09/04/2015
08/04/2015
07/04/2015
06/04/2015
02/04/2015
01/04/2015
31/03/2015
```

These refer to the weekdays in a year. Among these dates, I want to find the first date of the month. So for example, the month of June, the first date to be identified should be 02/06/2015 and for May be 04/05/2015.

I have tried something like this:

```
=IF(Cellreference=((Cellreference)-DAY(Cellreference)+1),TEXT(Cellreference,"mmm"),"")
```

But this only takes the first date of the month. I want it to be the first date in the month in the list of dates given.

Need some guidance on how to achieve this.

Comment: As the list seems to be ordered could you not try to detect when the month of the date you are inspecting is different from the month in the cell bellow?

Comment: hope this [Link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/datetime.htm) helps

Comment: You can use the function `Weekday()` to check if the date is a saturday (returned value=7) or sunday (returned value=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you use *Formula* so I can only suggest below:

```
=MIN(IF(MONTH(AllDateReference)=MONTH(CellReference),AllDateReference,1E+99))
```

This is an array formula entered using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>.
Actual sample:

```
=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$1:A$46)=MONTH(A1),A$1:A$46,1E+99))
```

where `A$1:A$46` contains all your dates.

**Edit1:** Display on first date of the month only.

```
=IF(A1=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$1:A$46)=MONTH(A1),A$1:A$46,1E+99)),A1,"")
```

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: very clever, one note: better use the month and year in the `if` formula

Comment: One thing, it appears as a number instead of the month. How to resolve it? Second thing, the same number appears for all the dates in the month. I need it to appear only on the first date of the month. How to do it?

Comment: @lakesh To make it appear as month, you just need to format it correctly. To make it appear only on the first day of the month, just add another `IF` for that.

Comment: @lakesh Added a screen shot and the actual formula used.